# Kafka does not react to listeners config

Tags: apache-kafka

Using kafka config:

```
# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

Netstat gives me this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Everything is default and kafka version is kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2.
I expected kafka to listen to port 9092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 9999 is JMX, and kafka does not start for other reasons.

I did this on my system:

```
sudo -u kafka /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /etc/kafka/server.properties
```

And surely:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
```

which just means I don't have zookeeper running, and then zookeper logs:

```
Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running
```

and now I need to start zookeeper on other node. Finally kafka has started.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9092                 :::*                    LISTEN
```